# R filter a variable by the count of another variable, but only counted within a day interval max

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the dataframe that I am working with:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Patient, ~date, ~Doctor
  "A", "2020-01-01", "A",
  "A", "2020-03-01", "A",
  "A", "2020-04-30", "B",
  "A", "2020-06-29", "C",
  "A", "2020-08-28", "A",
  "B", "2020-01-01", "A",
  "B", "2020-03-01","B",
  "B", "2020-04-30","B",
  "B", "2020-06-29","B",
  "B", "2020-08-28","C",
  "C", "2020-04-30","A",
  "C", "2020-06-29","A",
  "C", "2020-08-28","B",
  "C", "2020-10-27","C",
  "C", "2020-12-26","A",
)
```

As you can see, there are three columns: `Patient`, `date`, and `Doctor`.

Here is the desired dataframe that I am working towards.

```
desired_df <- tribble(
  ~Patient, ~Number_of_Diff_Doctors_within_180_days, 
  "A", "3", 
  "B", "2", 
  "C", "3", 
)
```

Here is the logic:
I'm trying to return a dataframe with one unique value for each patient and the number of doctors that that patient has seen in a 180-day window. This 180-day period is like a moving window, and the job is to figure out the maximum number of doctors seen during any 180-day window for the patient.

In the example, Patient A has three different doctors, doctors A, B, and C, within 2020-03-01 to 2020-06-29, which is <180 window, so this patient gets a code for 1 corresponding to three doctors. But Patient B, who also has three doctors, sees Doctor A on 2020-01-01 and Doctor C on day 2020-08-28, so only has two doctors in any 180-day window. And Patient C is the same as Patient A in the intervals, except the days are shifted forward.

Here is my attempt so far. It doesn't do anything about the date logic because I didn't know what I was doing with all that.

```
attempt <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(Patient, Doctor) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Patient, Doctor) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Patient) %>%
  tally() %>%
  filter(n > 1)
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data - rather, post data frame/tibble excerpts inline.

Comment: Can you state the constraints you're trying to achieve more clearly?  Even pseudo-code or a logical expression would be helpful.  It's a little hard to understand from your written explanation.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I fixed the entire post. Removed the screenshots and replaced with tables, and also changed the variables in the data so the problem is more real, and finally I  also changed the text, so I hope it's more clearly explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `runner` package for rolling window computations like this.  It's wonderful.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(runner)


df <- tribble(
    ~Patient, ~date, ~Doctor,
    "A", "2020-01-01", "A",
    "A", "2020-03-01", "A",
    "A", "2020-04-30", "B",
    "A", "2020-06-29", "C",
    "A", "2020-08-28", "A",
    "B", "2020-01-01", "A",
    "B", "2020-03-01","B",
    "B", "2020-04-30","B",
    "B", "2020-06-29","B",
    "B", "2020-08-28","C",
    "C", "2020-04-30","A",
    "C", "2020-06-29","A",
    "C", "2020-08-28","B",
    "C", "2020-10-27","C",
    "C", "2020-12-26","A",
) %>% 
    mutate(date = ymd(date))

df %>% 
    group_by(Patient) %>% 
    mutate(num_docs = runner(Doctor, n_distinct, k = 180, idx = date)) %>% 
    summarize(num_docs = max(num_docs))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Patient num_docs
  <chr>      <int>
1 A              3
2 B              2
3 C              3
```

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for the suggestion. Do you think it’s fast? Without exaggeration my file is tens of millions of observations

Comment: Yes, I think it's fast.  It's faster than other rolling window packages I've tried.  I've used it successfully to refactor slow code which I applied to 20 million rows of data.

Comment: Part of the speed depends on the function you're applying to each window.  At the bottom of the package's website https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/ it mentions there are some common functions that have been optimized.

Comment: You should probably sort your data first.  It helps the CPU cache be more efficient.

Comment: I didn’t think of that. Sort by patient, then date, you think?

Comment: Yes.  Patient and then date

Comment: Also, group_by/summarize can be slow for large data sets.  The `collapse` package is excellent for speeding up slow summaries.  The syntax is slightly different, but it's way easier than learning `data.table`.

Comment: This was a great solution. Only edit I would make is that I had to first type arrange(Patient, date) before the group_by otherwise I would get an error: 
Caused by error in `window_run()`:
! idx have to be in ascending order

Comment: Glad it worked out.  I didn't notice it needed sortin because the sample data was already sorted. How was the speed?

Comment: Fast, actually, I was impressed!

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution per OP edits.

First let's get a tidy data frame with cumulative days across a patient's visits:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  group_by(Patient) %>% 
  mutate(days_btwn = replace_na(day(days(date - lag(date))), 0),
         cum_days = cumsum(days_btwn)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Sample `df2` output:

```
# A tibble: 15 × 5
   Patient date       Doctor days_btwn cum_days
   <chr>   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A       2020-01-01 A              0        0
 2 A       2020-03-01 A             60       60
 3 A       2020-04-30 B             60      120
 4 A       2020-06-29 C             60      180
 5 A       2020-08-28 A             60      240
 6 B       2020-01-01 A              0        0
#...
```

Next, we can loop over each `Patient` (basically a group-by operation), and iteratively sample the rolling windows of visit periods. Compute the max number of unique `Doctor` values in each window where the total number of days is <= 180, and combine all patients' results in one data frame.

```
unique(df2$Patient) %>% 
  map_dfr(function(pat) {
    this_pat <- df2 %>% filter(Patient == pat)
    n_obs <- nrow(this_pat)
    max_docs <- n_distinct(this_pat$Doctor)
    n_docs <- 0
    max_win_docs <- 0
    for (i in 1:n_obs) {
      for (j in 1:n_obs) {
        win_days <- abs(this_pat$cum_days[j] - this_pat$cum_days[i])
        if (win_days <= 180) {
          n_docs <- n_distinct(this_pat %>% slice(i:j) %>% select(Doctor))
          if (n_docs > max_win_docs) max_win_docs <- n_docs
          if (max_win_docs == max_docs) next
        }
      }
    }
    list(patient = pat, n_diff_docs_within_180 = max_win_docs)
  }
)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  patient n_diff_docs_within_180
  <chr>                    <int>
1 A                            3
2 B                            2
3 C                            3
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks so much for the quick reply. I went through your solution carefully and then I had to change my post just a bit to be a little more clear. I added another three lines to the small data frame example and updated the explanation. The problem is, there are actually multiple customer_id values with multiple sales_id values -- these pairings can appear dozens of times. I need to figure out a way to include the customer id value anytime the customer_id appears with a different sales_id within 100 days of each other

Comment: Updated solution. There may be a nicer way to do this with either `zoo` or `RcppRoll` packages, but the conditional of max window sized paired with the unique string count made it easier to just write out in old-fashioned nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ambiguous what you mean by "within 180 days". Within 180 days of what date?

This determines the number of distinct doctors visited by each patient within 180 days of each visit.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date:=as.Date(date)]
df[, date.hi:=date+180]
result <- df[df, on=.(Patient, date>=date, date<=date.hi)]
result[, .(count=uniqueN(Doctor)), by=.(Patient, date)]
       Patient       date count
##  1:       A 2020-01-01     3
##  2:       A 2020-03-01     3
##  3:       A 2020-04-30     3
##  4:       A 2020-06-29     2
##  5:       A 2020-08-28     1
##  6:       B 2020-01-01     2
##  7:       B 2020-03-01     2
##  8:       B 2020-04-30     2
##  9:       B 2020-06-29     2
## 10:       B 2020-08-28     1
## 11:       C 2020-04-30     3
## 12:       C 2020-06-29     3
## 13:       C 2020-08-28     3
## 14:       C 2020-10-27     2
## 15:       C 2020-12-26     1
```

So, Patient A visited 3 doctors within 180 days of 2020-01-01 (row 1), but only 2 doctors within 180 days of 2020-06-29 (row 4). Obviously, if the dataset ends less than 180 days after a given date we really don't know the number of visits that will occur in that time frame.

The expected result in your question seems to be based off the first visit for each patient. We can extract that as follows:

```
result[, .(count=uniqueN(Doctor)), by=.(Patient, date)][, .SD[1], by=.(Patient)]
##    Patient       date count
## 1:       A 2020-01-01     3
## 2:       B 2020-01-01     2
## 3:       C 2020-04-30     3
```

**EDIT**: based on OP comment.
Max count for each patient is given by

```
result[, .(count=uniqueN(Doctor)), by=.(Patient, date)][
       , .(maxCount=max(count)),   by=.(Patient)]
##    Patient maxCount
## 1:       A        3
## 2:       B        2
## 3:       C        3
```

Comment: thanks so much for the response. Just to clarify I'm looking for is the max number of visits in any 180 day interval